# Does Teradata support macro variables or smth or anything like that?

Tags: sql, macros, teradata

For example, I have an report that should be refreshed monthly, and the code looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE report_date = '2017-10-01'
;

SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b on a.key = b.key
WHERE b.date = '2017-10-01'
;
```

Is there any possibility to replace date in every statement with macro variable, that is invoked once? The code might look like this:

```
LET macro_var = '2017-10-01';

SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE report_date = <macro_var>
;

SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b on a.key = b.key
WHERE b.date =  <macro_var>
;
```

Thanks

Comment: This is (usually) handled by the SQL client tool, not by the databas itself

Comment: I'm using Teradata SQL Assistant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In teradata, you can create a `parameterized macro` for this as below.

```
CREATE MACRO macro1(r_date date) AS (
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE report_date = :r_date;

SELECT a.*,
       b.*
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON a.key1 = b.key1
WHERE b.report_date = :r_date;
);
```

You can run it using

```
exec macro1('2017-10-01');
```

OR

```
exec macro1(DATE '2017-10-01'); -- recommended
```

---

**Update:**

In Teradata SQL Assitant, to insert variables into your code is to use a question mark followed by the variable name as below.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE report_date = '?r_date';


SELECT a.*,
       b.*
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON a.key1 = b.key1
WHERE b.report_date = '?r_date';
```

Upon pressing `F5` or Execute button, it will pop up for value for variable `r_date`

Comment: Hello zarruq, thank you, but I did not get the second part of your answer clearly. If I use '?r_date' - where should I declare it?

Comment: No need to declare. SQL Assistant treats `?[variableName]` as runtime variable, for which the value is needed so it will automatically shows a popup asking for value.

Answer (score 0):

i am using your code, but i show the next error

> Creat4 Macro Failed 3524: The user does not have CREATE MACRO access
> to database PROD_DWH_CONSULTA

```
CREATE MACRO macro1(r_date date) AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM PROD_DWH_CONSULTA.ENTIDADES
  WHERE Fecha_Act = :r_date;
);

exec macro1(DATE '2017-10-01'); -- recommended
```

Comment: You can usually create macros within your user, i.e. `CREATE MACRO myLoginUser.macro1`. Otherwise ask the DBA for the missing access right.